# POP OS mouse gestures using fusuma

Tags: linux, gesture

I have tried to enable tap gestures using fusuma which is working for swipe and pinch controls but I can't get the tap function to work, any help guys?

Here is my config file

```
swipe:
  3:
    left:
      command: 'xdotool key alt+Left'
    right:
      command: 'xdotool key alt+right'
    up:
      command: 'xdotool key super'
    down:
      command: 'xdotool key super'
  4:
    left:
      command: 'xdotool key ctrl+alt+Down'
    right:
      command: 'xdotool key ctrl+alt+Up'
    up:
      command: 'xdotool key ctrl+alt+Down'
    down:
      command: 'xdotool key ctrl+alt+Up'
pinch:
  in:
    command: 'xdotool key ctrl+plus'
  out:
     command: 'xdotool key ctrl+minus'

threshold:
  swipe: 0.4
  pinch: 0.4

interval:
  swipe: 0.8
  pinch: 0.1

tap:
  3:
   command: 'xdotool key super'


plugin:
  inputs:
    libinput_command_input:
      enable-tap: true
      verbose: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed fusuma-plugin-tap?

You can install it with `$gem install fusuma-plugin-tap`.